# add_rewrite_rule не работает

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');
function do_rewrite(){
    // Правило перезаписи
    add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ){
        $vars[] = 'food';
        $vars[] = 'variety';
        return $vars;
    } );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^(rewrite)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'page.php?pagename=$matches[1]&food=$matches[2]&variety=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}
```

Переходя по
https://www.bazar.club/rewrite?food=test&variety=mood
линк остается и не меняется на https://www.bazar.club/rewrite/test/mood
вызов `echo get_query_var('food');` работает.
в чем проблема ?

Comment: Заметка не по сути вопроса, но всё же: никогда не ставьте flush_rewrite_rules() на каждую загрузку страницы,  это очень тяжёлая и дорогая операция. Только на активацию плагина.

Comment: @KAGGDesign +1. Очень часто попадается вызов этой функции где попало. Как будто где-то есть популярный пример, который все тянут к себе с одной и той же ошибкой

Comment: @alenkins да откуда. Как всегда, с сайта Рудрастых: https://misha.agency/wordpress/wp_rewrite.html